# `Access violation in stack` when using versioned transactions (v0 + Lookup Table)

Tags: transactions

I created a dummy anchor program that takes in 40 accounts -- too many for a legacy tx to carry (intentionally).

I've written a test that uses a LUT to stuff all 40 and then fires off the tx against the contract.

The test fails with:

```
 SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/ilmoi/Downloads/my-vers-prog/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5054:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/ilmoi/Downloads/my-vers-prog/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5013:20)
    at Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/ilmoi/Downloads/my-vers-prog/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4961:14) {
  logs: [
    'Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS invoke [1]',
    'Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS consumed 9869 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 3 at address 0x200003930 of size 8 by instruction #3026',
    'Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
```

So: `Stack violation error`.

Important: if I reduce number of accounts to 25 (fits into a normal tx) - there is no error. So something isn't working around the lookup table.

Full code here: https://github.com/ilmoi/my-versioned-program

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `skipPreflight: true` and check `.anchor/program-logs`.

It seems like `Anchor` limitation, did you try a `native` program?

```
    Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 3 at address 0x200003930 of size 8 by instruction #3026
```

```
Streaming transaction logs mentioning Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS. Confirmed commitment
Transaction executed in slot 8:
  Signature: 2GNfNVXmMKo4cBFgvJJgm1bGPSPQSzcGYvChfmtY8ch35PxWjNuZbfrSYgmJgeSiHSd5shtMFZYyUz8QautWLfxS
  Status: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
  Log Messages:
    Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS invoke [1]
    Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS consumed 9869 of 200000 compute units
    Program failed to complete: Access violation in stack frame 3 at address 0x200003930 of size 8 by instruction #3026
    Program Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS failed: Program failed to complete
```

(I'm unable to reproduce it, something messing with the test validator logs)

Comment: skipPreflight won't help, haven't tried with a native program. Wait is that the error you're getting when you run the code from the repo I shared? huh why is it different

Comment: It's different because of `skipPreflight` , you were getting the simulation error which is usually insufficient , to get full details need to let the test validator run it and get the error I pasted. And yes, was running your repo.

Comment: hold on you're right, the actual error is stack violation. Could be an anchor thing.

Comment: yeah anchor thing - if you do 2x instructions with 25accs each in a single tx, everything works - see latest push in the same repo